# Erosion and Dilation in Windows phone???

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, image-processing, writeablebitmap

i trying to apply the Erosion and Dilation algorithms in my app for Windows Phone :).

But is very hard to do :(   i investigated for some example and i found this http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/FaceLight--Silverlight-4-Real-Time-Face-Detection

FaceLight for Silverlight.

Is a very good example and that have Erode and Dilate algorithms , but my app have some differences , FaceLight take a picture from camera and I want my app load some image from Gallery and apply that algorithms.

I follow this steps 
1.- Load the image from gallery.

```
PhotoChooserTask photo = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photo.Completed += (s, ee) =>
        {



            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            image.SetSource(ee.ChosenPhoto);

            image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

            this.imgoriginal.Source = image;

            GrayTimer.Start();



        };

        photo.Show();
```

2.- get the grayscale image from the orignal image.

```
 WriteableBitmap grayimg = Operations.doGray(imgoriginal); // get the grayscale image 

        BitmapImage imggray = new BitmapImage();

        stream = new MemoryStream(grayimg.ToByteArray()); // get the array of the image

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            grayimg.SaveJpeg(stream, 320, 240, 0, 90); // resize and set quality
            imggray.SetSource(stream);
            grayImage.Source = imggray;// set the grayscale image in the control.
        });
```

this the method DoGray()

```
  public static WriteableBitmap doGray(Image image)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(image, null);
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.PixelHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.PixelWidth; x++)
            {
                int pixelLocation = bitmap.PixelWidth * y + x;
                int pixel = bitmap.Pixels[pixelLocation];
                byte[] pixelbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(pixel);
                byte bwPixel = (byte)(.299 * pixelbytes[2] + .587 * pixelbytes[1] + .114 * pixelbytes[0]);
                pixelbytes[0] = bwPixel;
                pixelbytes[1] = bwPixel;
                pixelbytes[2] = bwPixel;
                bitmap.Pixels[pixelLocation] = BitConverter.ToInt32(pixelbytes, 0);
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

All works fine.

[image: Original Image]

[image: GrayScale Image]

Now  I apply the Erode Algorithm from FaceLight.

```
WriteableBitmap g;

        BitmapImage imggray = new BitmapImage();

        imggray =(BitmapImage) grayImage.Source; // get the gray image from the Control.


        g = new WriteableBitmap(imggray);

        // i apply 3 times for try to see something :S
        er = Operations.Erode(g);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            Stream str = new MemoryStream(er.ToByteArray());
            BitmapImage r = new BitmapImage();
            WriteableBitmap n;
            er.SaveJpeg(str, 320, 240,0, 100);
            r.SetSource(str);
            n = new WriteableBitmap(r);
            er = Operations.Erode(n);

        }

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream(er.ToByteArray());
            BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
            er.SaveJpeg(stream, 320, 240, 0, 100);
            result.SetSource(stream);
            imgerode.Source = result;
        });
```

Here is the Erode algorithm

```
// Process method of the Erode5x5Filter class
    public static WriteableBitmap Erode(WriteableBitmap input)
    {
        var p = input.Pixels;
        var w = input.PixelWidth;
        var h = input.PixelHeight;
        var result = new WriteableBitmap(w, h);
        var rp = result.Pixels;
        var empty = 0; // = 0
        int c, cm;
        int i = 0;

        // Erode every pixel
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++, i++)
            {
                // Middle pixel
                cm = p[y * w + x];
                if (cm == empty) { continue; }

                // Row 0
                // Left pixel
                if (x - 2 > 0 && y - 2 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 2) * w + (x - 2)];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }
                // Middle left pixel
                if (x - 1 > 0 && y - 2 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 2) * w + (x - 1)];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }
                if (y - 2 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 2) * w + x];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }
                if (x + 1 < w && y - 2 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 2) * w + (x + 1)];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }
                if (x + 2 < w && y - 2 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 2) * w + (x + 2)];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }

                // Row 1
                // Left pixel
                if (x - 2 > 0 && y - 1 > 0)
                {
                    c = p[(y - 1) * w + (x - 2)];
                    if (c == empty) { continue; }
                }


                // ... 
                // ... Process the rest of the 24 neighboring pixels
                // ...


                // If all neighboring pixels are processed 
                // it's clear that the current pixel is not a boundary pixel.
                rp[i] = cm;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and here is the result :S nothing happens :(

[image: Erosion image]

**and the same issue with Dilate algorithm  but the result image is a blank image .
Any ideas o suggestions?? I need help please.**

Answer (score 0):

I quickly took a look a your erode method. Why didn't you write a loop (actually two for loops going from -2 to +2) to handle the 25 cases you are trying to handle?

Comment: I don't think it's his code - he said it's from FaceLight which is a library

Comment: I my own solution: I used AForge.NET Framework via WCF , i send the images to the WCF from Windows Phone and the WCF back the result Image :).

Answer (score 0):

Although the Erode function looks like it should work on grayscale, have you tried thresholding your image to a binary mask (e.g. rp = p > 127 ? 255 : 0) before calling erode?

The code you have here for the Erode function also never changes `i` from 0...